# C# : changing listbox row color?

Tags: c#, listbox

I am trying to change the background color of some rows in a `ListBox`. I have two lists that one has names and is displayed in a `ListBox`. The second list has some similar values as the first `List`. When clicking a button, I want to search the `ListBox` and the second `List`, and change the color of the `ListBox` for those values that appear in the `List`. My search in the `ListBox` is as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < students.Count; j++)
    {
        if (listBox1.Items[i].ToString().Contains(students[j].ToString()))
        {
        }
    }
}
```

But I don't know which method to use in order to change the appearance of a `ListBox` row. Can anybody help me?

**EDIT: **

HI I wrote my code as follows:

```
private void ListBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    e.DrawBackground();
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    Brush myBrush = Brushes.Black;
    Brush myBrush2 = Brushes.Red;
    g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Silver), e.Bounds);
    e.Graphics.DrawString(listBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString(), e.Font, myBrush, e.Bounds, StringFormat.GenericDefault);
    for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < existingStudents.Count; j++)
        {
            if (listBox1.Items[i].ToString().Contains(existingStudents[j]))
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawString(listBox1.Items[i].ToString(),
                e.Font, myBrush2, e.Bounds, StringFormat.GenericDefault);
            }
        }
    }
    e.DrawFocusRectangle();
}
```

Now it draws my `List` in the `ListBox`, but when I click the button first, it shows in red only the students that are in the `List` and when I click on the `ListBox` it  draws all the elements. I want that it will show all the elements , and when I click the button it will show all the elements and the element found in the `List` in red. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Draw it yourself using OwnerDraw: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/sahuja/OwnerDrawListBox11212005014826AM/OwnerDrawListBox.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243870/changing-selected-itms-color-in-a-listbox

Comment: After your update: apparently you're not getting what the previous answerers below showed you. The DrawItem method _draws one item_, not multiple items. You're going to need to handle _each item as needed_, and **not** use a for loop to process _all_ items. Take a look at Thomas Levesque's or Justin's answer for good examples.

Comment: But if I want to show two record in listbox? I could not do this? 2 record of 5 will change color ,others will be same color.

Comment: What is your condition for one record to change color and the others to show the same color? How could you programmatically tell the difference?

Comment: In my program I am getting bluetooth MAcAddresses for students and compairing them with existing macAddresses in that moment.In my lixtbox before scaning list of all group shown .After scan there must be high lited student which exist that moment.For this I am compaining Listbox1.items[i].Contains(existingstudents[i]). and this geves me students names which are existing on that moment.This idea works but changing color of listbox for spesific users not work )_

Comment: Draw the text after the back grounds because drawing it first deletes the string
e.DrawFocusRectangle();
 e.Graphics.DrawString(listBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString(), e.Font, myBrush, e.Bounds, StringFormat.GenericDefault);

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Background color of a ListBox item (winforms)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/91747/background-color-of-a-listbox-item-winforms)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I find solution that instead of using ListBox I used ListView.It allows to change list items  BackColor.

```
private void listView1_Refresh()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        listView1.Items[i].BackColor = Color.Red;
        for (int j = 0; j < existingStudents.Count; j++)
        {
            if (listView1.Items[i].ToString().Contains(existingStudents[j]))
            {
                listView1.Items[i].BackColor = Color.Green;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Am I missing something here? The question was for ListBox and the answer is for ListView control.

Answer (score 25):

You will need to draw the item yourself.  Change the DrawMode to OwnerDrawFixed and handle the DrawItem event.

```
/// <summary>
/// Handles the DrawItem event of the listBox1 control.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
/// <param name="e">The <see cref="System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
private void listBox1_DrawItem( object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e )
{
   e.DrawBackground();
   Graphics g = e.Graphics;

    // draw the background color you want
    // mine is set to olive, change it to whatever you want
    g.FillRectangle( new SolidBrush( Color.Olive), e.Bounds );

    // draw the text of the list item, not doing this will only show
    // the background color
    // you will need to get the text of item to display
    g.DrawString( THE_LIST_ITEM_TEXT , e.Font, new SolidBrush( e.ForeColor ), new PointF( e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y) );

    e.DrawFocusRectangle();
}
```

Comment: thanks for comment but  how will I use this function?or where? I changed in properties of listbox to Drawmode = OwnerDrawFixed  and in InitializeComponent() am I have to correct some think? or simply I will add this function to my Form1.cs function and it will call it?

Comment: I'm a VS designer fan.  So in the form editor where your listbox is go into the event list and create a new handler for the DrawItem event.  Then use the above code in your new event handler.

Comment: To use the draw item handler:


listBox1.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
listBox1.DrawItem += new DrawItemEventHandler(listBox1_DrawItem);

Comment: if you want the same item text, instead of `THE_LIST_ITEM_TEXT`, you can put `(sender as ListBox).Items[e.Index].ToString()`

Comment: This answer seems correct, I tried it to achieve the color with LISTBOX, the color works, but if you add several rows enough for the scrollbar to appear, the render gets all dirty. It's impossible to be used.

Answer (score 19):

First use this Namespace:

```
using System.Drawing;
```

Add this anywhere on your form:

```
listBox.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
listBox.DrawItem += listBox_DrawItem;
```

Here is the Event Handler:

```
private void listBox_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
     e.DrawBackground();

     Graphics g = e.Graphics;
     g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.White), e.Bounds);
     ListBox lb = (ListBox)sender;
     g.DrawString(lb.Items[e.Index].ToString(), e.Font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), new PointF(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y));

     e.DrawFocusRectangle();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to draw the listitems yourself to achieve this.

[Here's a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91747/background-color-of-a-listbox-item-winforms) with the same kind of question.

Answer (score 2):

Once you've added your listbox item to your form, change **DrawMode** with **OwnerDrawFixed** option from the **Properties** panel. If you forget to do this, none of the codes below will work. Then click **DrawItem** event from the **Events** area.

```
private void listBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
   // 1. Get the item
   string selectedItem = listBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString();
                    
   // 2. Choose font 
   Font font = new Font("Arial", 12);
        
   // 3. Choose colour
   SolidBrush solidBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
        
   // 4. Get bounds
   int left = e.Bounds.Left;
   int top = e.Bounds.Top;
                    
   // 5. Use Draw the background within the bounds
   e.DrawBackground();
        
   // 6. Colorize listbox items
   e.Graphics.DrawString(selectedItem, font, solidBrush, left, top);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution for listbox items' background to yellow. I  tried the following solution to achieve the output.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < lstEquipmentItem.Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    if ((bool)ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Valid_Equipment"] == false)
                    {
                        lblTKMWarning.Text = "Invalid Equipment & Serial Numbers are highlited.";
                        lblTKMWarning.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                        lstEquipmentItem.Items[i].Attributes.Add("style", "background-color:Yellow");
                        Count++;
                    }

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I did it also allows for you change the background color if the item is selected.

```
private void lbLog_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    Color color;

    if ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected)
        color = Color.Blue;
    else
        color = e.Index % 2 == 0 ? Color.Gray : Color.White;

    g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(color), e.Bounds);
    g.DrawString(lbLog.Items[e.Index].ToString(), e.Font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), e.Bounds, StringFormat.GenericDefault);

    e.DrawFocusRectangle();
}
```

Answer (score -6):

How about

```
      MyLB is a listbox

        Label ll = new Label();
        ll.Width = MyLB.Width;
        ll.Content = ss;
        if(///<some condition>///)
            ll.Background = Brushes.LightGreen;
        else
            ll.Background = Brushes.LightPink;
        MyLB.Items.Add(ll);
```

Comment: It is obvious that you never tried that code. It does not work. It does not even compile. It seems that you are a Java programmer. In Java it is done this way. But C# is COMPLETELY different.

Comment: Why did you expect it to compile? it's meta code.  
Well, I've been designing & writing code for about 50 years only:)  
Obviously I wouldn't hire you if all you can do is look for copy / paste answers.

Comment: This code is complete crap. You cannot put a label into a listbox. It shows that you did not learn programming C#, not even within 50 years.