# Change List colour in ListBox

Tags: c#, winforms, list, listboxitem

**C#**
I currently have a win form and I can display two lists that I have in a Listbox, however since the two lists are merged the data can be a bit confusing to look at. Is there anyway that I can set List 1's item colour to blue and List 2's item colour to red?

```
private void updatesum()
{
  listBox.Items.Clear();
  List<String> listOfDels = theDatabase.listDeliveries();
  List<String> listofPicks = theDatabase.listPickups();

  listBox.Items.AddRange(listOfDels.ToArray());
  listBox.Items.AddRange(listofPicks.ToArray());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to subscribe the DrawItem of the ListBox and paint yourself the BackColor:

```
listBox.DrawItem += new DrawItemEventHandler(listBox_DrawItem);
```

I think your event should be something like this:

```
private void listBox_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    e.DrawBackground();
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;

    g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Blue), e.Bounds);

    g.DrawString(listBox.Items[e.Index].ToString(), 
        e.Font, Brushes.Black, e.Bounds, StringFormat.GenericDefault);

    e.DrawFocusRectangle();
}
```

Comment: Where would I put that first line, sorry i'm still learning c#

Comment: You could put it in your constructor or you can simply subscribe the event into the designer

Answer (score 0):

Check out some other answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554609/c-sharp-changing-listbox-row-color) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91747/background-color-of-a-listbox-item-winforms) to similar question SO. I have never done it before but they seem to fit the bill. Hope it helps.

Comment: Not really sure how i'd fit it into the code I have but thanks, it's cleared up some things

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help you more. I am terrible with the visual side of things.