# C# Color of listbox item continued

Tags: c#

I'm trying to find a way to highlight the background of list box items with different colors, and came across this four year old closed thread that almost answers the question here:

[Background color of a ListBox item (winforms)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91747/background-color-of-a-listbox-item-winforms#91758)

I'm not following how to use his method.  So if I created an object named listBox1 and a string variable named strSomeString, what would be the exact code for adding strSomeString to listBox1 with a red background?

Using Shadow Wizard's code here:

```
    private void lbReports_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        e.DrawBackground();

        bool selected = ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected);

        int index = e.Index;
        if (index >= 0 && index < lbReports.Items.Count)
        {
            string text = lbReports.Items[index].ToString();
            Graphics g = e.Graphics;

            Color color = (selected) ? Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.Highlight) : (((index % 2) == 0) ? Color.White : Color.Gray);
            g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(color), e.Bounds);

            // Print text
            g.DrawString(text, e.Font, (selected) ? reportsForegroundBrushSelected : reportsForegroundBrush, 
                lbReports.GetItemRectangle(index).Location);
        }

        e.DrawFocusRectangle();
    }
```

-Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# : changing listbox row color?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554609/c-sharp-changing-listbox-row-color)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using an [owner draw control](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/controls/creating-a-color-picker-with-an-owner-draw-combobox) for this.

It's more work because you need to render all the list contents. But you'll have total flexibility.

Comment: If I went that route instead, what would be an example block of code for adding strSomeString to listBox1 with lets say a red background?  Sorry kind of a C# newbie :)

Comment: Well, you could create a class that perhaps includes a string and color value. Adding it to the control would be dead easy. It's the rendering that needs work. At any rate, that's a link in my answer. There is sample code and other articles at the site about owner drawn controls.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to hook the Draw_item event of the listbox to lbReports_DrawItem handler.
You can do that by set it at the properties of the listbox.

Another thing is to Set the DrawMode to OwnerDrawFixed