# ListBoxItems selected color differs when programatically selecting the item

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

As you can see in the image below, the highlight/selected color differs when clicking with the mouse vs programatically selecting an item. When clicking an item, the selected color is a transparent blue. When programatically selecting an item, the selected color is grey?

How can I make it so when programatically selecting an item, it also is the transparent blue color that the system uses by default (when clicking with the mouse) ?

Thank you

Here is the simple code behind:

```cs
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                this.ListBoxTest.Items.Add(new ListBoxItem {Content = "Test " + i});
            }

            this.ListBoxTest.SelectedItem = this.ListBoxTest.Items[2];
        }
    }
}
```

The XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ListBox Name="ListBoxTest"></ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

When programatically selected (grey selection color)

[image: When programatically selected]

When selected via mouse click (light blue color)
[image: When clicked with mouse]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554609/c-sharp-changing-listbox-row-color

Comment: That has nothing to do with the question @OusmaneMahyDiaw - The default WPF selected listbox item color is transparent blue. Surely the selected color should be the same regardless of clicking an item or selecting it programatically. I'm not trying to change the color, I want to know why they differ. I want them to be the same, as it seems illogical that they are not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is set the focus to the listbox first

```
ListBoxTest.Focus();
```

Then you can select the item you want.

Comment: Lol. I was sure I tried that before asking this and it didn't work, but it's working now. I must have had the order mixed up. Thank you!

Comment: Haha it happens. happy i could help :)