# Add listbox items with different colors using a checkbox C#

Tags: c#, colors, listbox

I am adding items to a listbox via a textbox, and I would like to know how change the color of the listbox item that is added from the textbox when the checkbox is checked. So when I check the checkbox, the color in the textbox turns red and when I click the button to send the textbox to the listbox, the listbox item turns red. If I don't check the checkbox then the text color is black, so if the first one that is added and red, then I add to black ones, then in the listbox I need to see one red, and one black.

Thanks,

```
private void addEventButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        // Adds events to listbox. 
       if (this.titleTextBox.Text != "")
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(this.titleTextBox.Text); 
            listBox2.Items.Add(this.titleTextBox.Text);
            this.titleTextBox.Focus();
            this.titleTextBox.Clear();
```

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554609/c-sharp-changing-listbox-row-color) answer if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Handle the DrawItem event of the ListBox

```
private void listBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
   var someObj = listBox1.Items[e.Index] as MyClass;
   Color backColor = Color.Green;
   if (someObj.ID == someID) {
      backColor = Color.Gray;
   }

   // draw back color and text 
   var g = e.Graphics;

   //background:
   SolidBrush backgroundBrush = new SolidColorBrush(backcolor);
   g.FillRectangle(backgroundBrush, e.Bounds);

   //text:
   SolidBrush foregroundBrush = (selected) ? reportsForegroundBrushSelected : reportsForegroundBrush;
   g.DrawString(text, e.Font, foregroundBrush, lbReports.GetItemRectangle(index).Location);
}
```

Comment: But that only works if I were to click on the event in the listbox, not when I added it correct?