# c# Listbox_DrawItem and listbox_SelectedIndexChanged

Tags: c#, colors, listbox

I have a listbox_SelectedIndexChanged that is created on a form.  The items that populate this list box is from an array.  Is there a way to change the color of each item based on a rule?  Would I have to add a Listbox_DrawItem  to get the color?  I have no idea on how to get this going.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement the DrawItem event of the ListBox. Take a look at this post - [C# : changing listbox row color?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2555062/5395709)

In the future, please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide [Minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your question.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Looking through the post I saw that I could use ListView instead that will do what I need.