# C# mark found TEXT in listbox in red

Tags: c#, listbox, highlight, items

How can I mark a found TEXT in my listbox? First I'm searching for contain using this:

```
bool found = false;
 foreach (var item in listBox1.Items)
 {
     if(item.ToString().Equals("STOP"))
     {
         found = true;
         break;
     }
 }
if(!found)
    mark it in RED.
```

I want to highlight all the entire TEXT in red after finding the "STOP". Thank you!

Comment: When talking about controls, you need to use the tag for the appropriate technology. If this is a Windows Forms `ListBox`, please add the Windows Forms tag to your question. The same goes for WPF or whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the ListBox1_DrawItem to change the text color.

Sample Code:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    listBox1.DrawItem += ListBox1_DrawItem;
    listBox1.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;

    // Sample Data
    listBox1.Items.Add("24 CALL LBL 1");
    listBox1.Items.Add("25 L X+100 Y-150 R0 FMAX M92");
    listBox1.Items.Add("26 STOP");
    listBox1.Items.Add("STOP");
}

private void ListBox1_DrawItem(object? sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    ListBox lb = (ListBox)sender;
    var itemText = lb.Items[e.Index].ToString();
    var textColor = Color.Black;
    if(itemText.Contains("STOP")) textColor = Color.Red;

    e.DrawBackground();
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;       
    g.DrawString(lb.Items[e.Index].ToString(), e.Font, new SolidBrush(textColor), new PointF(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y));
    e.DrawFocusRectangle();
}
```

[image]

But I think ListView is better
[C# : changing listbox row color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554609/c-sharp-changing-listbox-row-color)

Comment: Thank you Antony, but it don't work and don't solve my problem.

Comment: @Wadim Do you have more error message or don't know anything else?

Comment: Maybe the problem is, that I open a TXT file and loading the content to the listbox. Some items contains the word "STOP". Maybe that is the problem? The code have to find the word "STOP" in all items and mark only the word (forecolor?) in red, not the hole item. THX!

Comment: @Wadim Sorry I misunderstood what you meant by highlight. I updated the answer.

Comment: TY you save my day. One question... how can I search the word "STOP" in an item, if the item containc other words. For example:

24 CALL LBL 1
25 L X+100 Y-150 R0 FMAX M92
26 STOP

I have to write: case " 24 CALL LBL 1 25 L X+100 Y-150 R0 FMAX M92 26 STOP":

but I don't know wich number is in front of each STOP, so I wont to search only STOP. Is that possible?

Comment: @Wadim your can try itemText.Contains("STOP"). I updated the answer, but you should read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/search-strings