# Set the font and color of a listbox item by code in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I'm busy with a customized list box that I use as a register reader in c#. Now I want to set a determined item in a determined item with a different font and color than the rest. I checked [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5065298/how-to-change-color-of-selected-item-in-listbox) and from the answers I made the following code:

```
private void myListBox_DrawItem(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    e.DrawBackground();
    Font myFont;
    Brush myBrush;
    int i = e.Index;

    if (e.Index == 3)
    {
        myFont = e.Font;
        myBrush = Brushes.Black;
    }
    else
    {
        myFont = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9.75f, FontStyle.Bold);
        myBrush = Brushes.CadetBlue;
    }

    e.Graphics.DrawString(myListBox.Items[i].ToString(), myFont, myBrush, e.Bounds, StringFormat.GenericDefault);
}
```

And call the method in my IntializeComponent() using

```
this.myListBox.DrawItem += new System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventHandler(this.myListBox_DrawItem);
```

The call does not throw an exception whatsoever, but I see no change on the line I want to handle. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Try calling Invalidate() in your combo to force a redraw.

Comment: Can you confirm that you've added `this.myListBox.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6896151/c-sharp-change-listbox-items-color might help

Comment: @keyboardP that was the problem!!!! I missed that call :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing one more line in your `IntializeComponent()` add this:

```
this.myListBox.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
```

before attaching an event.

Comment: Thanks!!! That was the problem, I wrote the call in my `InitializeComponent()` and now works perfectly :). Thanks