# Make ListBoxItem look bold

Tags: c#, webforms, listbox, formatting

I am adding items, consisting of two strings, to listbox one from DropDownList, the other one from TextBox. I want the one picked from TextBox look bold. How can I format only the txtStaff. Text after adding to ListBox.

```
ListBox1.Items.Add(ddlFilter.SelectedItem.Text + " " + txtStaff.Text);
```

Comment: What is the value of `txtStaff.Text`? How do you want to format it?

Comment: I just want it to look **bold** in the listbox.

Comment: you said you want to bold only textbox text?

Comment: txtStaff.Text is added to listbox. I just want it to be bold in the listbox. If the txtStaff.Text is "Car", then I want the **Car** inside the listbox to be bold.

Comment: I am afraid you need to do the drawing yourself. Set DrawMode = OwnerDraw and change whatever needed in OnDrawItem(). For Example check that question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17276303/set-the-font-and-color-of-an-listbox-item-by-code-in-c-sharp

Comment: Come on. Can't be that hard!

Comment: It is even harder! Because you just get a OnDrawItem! You need to make a markup to the part of the string you want to have a different font - to recognize it during drawing :-(

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
txtStaff.Font.Bold = True;
```

**OR**

use of **css**

**css**

```
.highlight
{
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

**code**

```
txtStaff.CssClass = "highlight";
```

**OR**

```
txtStaff.Attributes["style"] = "font-weight:bold;";
```

**Edit :-**

I am not sure but try it.

```
ListBox1.Items.Add(ddlFilter.SelectedItem.Text + " " + txtStaff.Text);
ListBox1.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
private void ListBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    e.DrawBackground();
    e.Graphics.DrawString(ListBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString(), new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, e.Bounds);
    e.DrawFocusRectangle();
}
```

it may help you.

Comment: All makes the txtStaff.Text in the TextBox bold, not in the ListBox.