# Draw text in all available fonts

Tags: c#, fonts

I have simple `ListBox` and i want to draw simple `text` in all available fonts in order to choose one that i like:

```
ListBox lb;
foreach (FontFamily font in System.Drawing.FontFamily.Families)
{
    Font f = new Font(font, 15);
    lbFonts.Items.Add(f.Name + ": " + "11");
}
```

Currently my `ListBox` is all with the same font.

Comment: That's because you're not using the fonts themselves, only their name...

Comment: Can i have example how to fix it ?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.drawitem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set the font and color of an listbox item by code in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17276303/set-the-font-and-color-of-an-listbox-item-by-code-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply add the Font itself to the list (or create a class, add a property for the font and size and overwrite the ToString()- Method ti get the text as in your sample).

This way you can use the approach [used here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17276303/set-the-font-and-color-of-an-listbox-item-by-code-in-c-sharp)

Add these lines for the initialization:

```
this.listBox1.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
this.listBox1.DrawItem += new System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventHandler(listBox1_DrawItem);

listBox1.ItemHeight = 20;
InstalledFontCollection installedFontCollection = new InstalledFontCollection();

foreach (FontFamily fontFamily in installedFontCollection.Families)
{
    FontListItem item = new FontListItem(fontFamily, 10);
    listBox1.Items.Add(item);
}
```

And the DrawItem-Method:

```
void listBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    e.DrawBackground();

    FontListItem item = (FontListItem)listBox1.Items[e.Index];

    e.Graphics.DrawString(item.ToString(), item.Font, Brushes.Black, e.Bounds, StringFormat.GenericDefault);
}
```

Sample class for adding the Font to the ListBox:

```
private class FontListItem
{
    public int Size { get; private set; }
    public Font Font { get; private set; }

    public FontListItem(FontFamily family, int size)
    {
        Font = new Font(family, size);
        Size = size;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        if(Font != null)
            return Font.Name + ": " + Size;
        return "[none]: " + Size;
    }
}
```

You should get an output similar to this:

[image: Sample output with listbox]

Comment: And if i want only to insert text of my own for each font ?

Comment: @roz I updated the answer, it's now implemented using a FontListItem class.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your real question is:

> How do I enumerate all installed fonts in .NET?

To which [Microsoft has written a How-To](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yf5t4e8(v=vs.110).aspx). The heart of it uses [InstalledFontCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.text.installedfontcollection(v=vs.110).aspx) to get at all the font families:

```
InstalledFontCollection installedFontCollection = new InstalledFontCollection();

// Get the array of FontFamily objects.
FontFamily[] fontFamilies = installedFontCollection.Families;
```

Iterate over this to populate your list box. Note that from a UI perspective, this is a horrible approach without a sort of some kind. Also, many users like to see a sample of that font, but using the font's name as the sample hurts the UI as there are are number of pictographic fonts (Zapf Dingbats, Wingdings, etc.) that can't render their own name in a useful manner.